# VB.Net equivalent for Indexer Initializer

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-6.0, initializer

Is there any VB.NET equivalent to the C#6 Indexer Initializer construct?

```
var placesByZip = new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         ["63368"] = "Dardenne Prairie",
         ["63141"] = "Des Peres",
         ["63101"] = "St. Louis"
     };
```

--Edit--

Just to be more precise, I'm looking for the Indexer Initializer (which is an object initializer), not the collection initializer.

More information on the difference can be found near the end of this [blog entry](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/05/08/c.net-little-wonders-indexer-initializer-syntax.aspx).

-- Edit2:

From the blog mentionned, the solution should allow to do this:

> Again, I wish to reiterate that the Indexer Initializer is not a type
>   of Collection Initializer, it’s a type of Object Initializer.  Why do
>   I keep saying this?  Why is this distinction important?  Because you
>   cannot mix object initializers and collection initializers in the same
>   initialization list.
>
> So, we can’t initialize a collection and set a property in the same
>   initialization list, but we can set a property, field, and indexer in
>   the same initialization list since they are all valid Object
>   Initializers.

Comment: `Dim placesByZip As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"63368", "Dardenne Prairie"}, {"63141", "Des Peres"}}`

Comment: @soohoonigan: This is the answer - you should post it as an answer.

Comment: From your link: `Now, in Dictionary the net result is the same, but keep in mind this isn’t necessarily true for all classes.` so maybe use something other than a Dictionary

Comment: Can I know why I got downvoted on this one? The question was precise I think but the answers simply missed the important thing which was to get the Indexer Initializer. Instead, the answers aimed at how to initialize a dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-06-27, VB.NET version 15.8 (VS 2017), object initialization from indexed members is not authorized according to [Microsoft documentation on object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types).

> Class members being initialized cannot be indexed or qualified

For completeness sake, neither is it mentioned in [collection initializers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/).

Answer (score 2):

There's no such feature in Visual Basic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/getting-started/whats-new

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```vb
Dim placesByZip as New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
{"63368", "Dardenne Prairie"}, 
{"63141", "Des Peres"},
{"63101", "St. Louis"}
}
```

(never tried it before)

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to the collection initializer syntax, but not the index initializer syntax.

Comment: The original example uses a string indexer, so if you change this to a Dictionary(Of String, String), and change the indexer values to strings, you will have it. (e.g., {"63368", "Dardenne Prairie"}, ... ).

Comment: Fair, I saw numbers so I wrote integer. @JonathonChase I don't know the difference, I simply wrote what i thought is the vb equivalent of c#

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
    Dim placesByZip As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
        {"63368", "Dardenne Prairie"},
        {"63141", "Des Peres"},
        {"63101", "St. Louis"}}
```

[Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/)

Comment: @CruleD already gave this answer (which is for Collection initializers and not Indexer initializer)

Comment: @bkqc: This is the correct answer.  Unlike C#, VB has no special syntax for indexer initializer.  And note that this answer is actually different from the one posted by CruleD.

Comment: @CruleD - before you edited your post it was not correct.